# How do you automate making gifs from videos?

Tags: photoshop, gif, mp4

I have around 50 video clips that I need to make into gifs. I'm aware of the process to make a gif using photoshop. I was wondering if there was a way to automate this so I don't have to spend too much time doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating actions in photoshop. Open one clip, create new action and record what you are doing. Then open all your clips and press play. Haven't tried it with clips yet but that's the auto way.
Other way, there are websites that convert clips into gifs. Both take same amount of time, but some websites are more prepared for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have linux or cygwin you can use ImageMagick.

```
convert -quiet -delay 1 plane.avi plane.gif
```

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/video/

Off the top of my head, you could do this as a shell script to do all 50 in a directory:

```
for file in *.avi; do
  convert -quiet -delay 1 "$file" $(basename "$file" ".avi").gif
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to do it programatically you can use http://gifserver.levy.se by adding the url to the video like `http://gifserver.levy.se?video=urlTovideo.mp4&format=json`

You can checkout the source from github at https://github.com/marlev/gifserver